# Accurate NDSolve for PDE with NIntegrate Functions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I have a function $A(c)$ which is defined by an integral. I wasn't able to solve it analytically, and therefore defined $A(c)$ using `NIntegrate`:

```
A[c_?NumericQ] := 2 NIntegrate[Sqrt[(3 + 5 y^4 + c (1 + 4 y^2 - y^4) - Sqrt[(-1 + c) (-9 + 42 y^2 - 17 y^4 + c (-7 - 10 y^2 + y^4))] + y^2 (-12 + Sqrt[(-1 + c) (-9 + 42 y^2 - 17 y^4 + c (-7 - 10 y^2 + y^4))]))/(1 + c + (-5 + c) y^2 + 2 y^4)]/Sqrt[2],
{y, -Sqrt[((3 - Sqrt[9 - 7 c^2 - 2 c] + c)/(2 + 2 c))], Sqrt[(3 - Sqrt[9 - 7 c^2 - 2 c] + c)/(2 + 2 c)]}]
```

Using $A(c)$ I define a function $rsqr(x,y)$:

```
rsqr[x_, y_] := 1/(2 π)A[1 - 4/(1/(x + 1)^2 + 1/(y + 1)^2 + 1/(x - 1)^2 + 1/(y - 1)^2)]
```

I want to solve the following first order PDE for the function $\alpha(x,y)$:
$$\partial_{x}rsqr\partial_{y}\alpha-\partial_{y}rsqr\partial_{x}\alpha=1$$
The region is $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ rectangle, and the boundry condition is $\alpha(x,0)=0$ (I know it is insufficient boundry conditions, but doesn't seem to be a problem).
First, I have to calculate the derivatives of $rsqr(x,y)$. Following [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277417/nintegrate-gives-the-wrong-result) I have asked, I calculate the derivatives numerically using finite-differences:

```
h = 10^-5;
drsqrdx[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{(rsqr[x + h, y] - rsqr[x - h, y])/(2 h), h < x < 1 - h},
{(rsqr[x, y] - rsqr[x - h, y])/h, x >= 1 - h},
{(rsqr[x + h, y] - rsqr[x, y])/h, x <= h}}]
drsqrdy[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{(rsqr[x, y + h] - rsqr[x, y - h])/(2 h), h < y < 1 - h},
{(rsqr[x, y] - rsqr[x, y - h])/h, y >= 1 - h},
{(rsqr[x, y + h] - rsqr[x, y])/h, y <= h}}]
```

Now I try to solve the PDE:

```
NDSolve[{drsqrdx[x, y] \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(y\)]\(α[x, y]\)\) - drsqrdy[x, y] \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x\)]\(α[x, y]\)\) == 1, α[x, 0] == 0}
,α, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

But for some reason it gives a warning:
`Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered.`. Therefore I try to solve in $[0,1-\epsilon]\times[0,1-\epsilon]$ rectangle for small $\epsilon$ in hope the interpolating function would approximate it in the whole rectangle:

```
ϵ = 10^-6;
αsol = NDSolve[{drsqrdx[x, y] \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(y\)]\(α[x, y]\)\) - drsqrdy[x, y] \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x\)]\(α[x, y]\)\) == 1, α[x, 0] == 0}
,α, {x, 0, 1-ϵ}, {y, 0, 1-ϵ}]
```

It takes a long time and produces warnings, but gives a solution. The problem is that the solution does not satisfy the equation. By plotting $\partial_{x}rsqr\partial_{y}\alpha-\partial_{y}rsqr\partial_{x}\alpha-1$ we can see a significant deviation from $0$ in some places, especially near the origin:

```
dαdx[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{(α[x + h, y] - α[x - h, y])/(2 h), h < x < 1 - h},
{(α[x, y] - α[x - h, y])/h, x >= 1 - h},
{(α[x + h, y] - α[x, y])/h, x <= h}}] /. αsol[[1]]
dαdy[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{(α[x, y + h] - α[x, y - h])/(2 h), h < y < 1 - h},
{(α[x, y] -α[x, y - h])/h, y >= 1 - h},
{(α[x, y + h] - α[x, y])/h, y <= h}}] /. αsol[[1]]
Plot3D[{drsqrdx[x, y] dαdy[x, y] - drsqrdy[x, y] dαdx[x, y] - 1, 0},
{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 0.5}]
```

[image]

I tried to change many options, such as adding `MaxStepSize -> 0.01` on `NDSolve`, increasing `AccuracyGoal`, `PrecisionGoal` or `WorkingPrecision` for `NDSolve` and `NIntegrate`, and trying many `Method`s of `NDSolve` and `NIntegrate`. While it does give better results in some cases, and does not produce warnings (except insufficient boundry conditions), the results still never satisfy the PDE.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem and find a solution to the PDE?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Knowledge of  `A[c]`  here we try to create a FEM-solution using `ElementMeshInterpolation`.

mesh definition:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1 , 1 }]   ,"MeshElementType" ->TriangleElement  , "MeshOrder" -> 1 , "MaxCellMeasure" -> .001  ]
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

elementmeshinterpolation:

```
xy = mesh["Coordinates"];
z = Map[1/(2 Pi) A[arg[ #[[1]], #[[2]] ] ]  &, xy] ;
rsqr = ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, z ]; (* rsqr[x,y]*)
```

ElementMeshInterpolation allows extrapolation, that's why we don't need piecewise-functionality

```
h = 10^-3;
drsqrdx = ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh,Map[(rsqr[#[[1]] + h, #[[2]]] - rsqr[#[[1]] - h, #[[2]]])/(2 h) &, xy]];
drsqrdy = ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh,Map[(rsqr[#[[1]], #[[2]] + h] -rsqr[#[[1]], #[[2]] - h])/(2 h) &,  xy]];
```

FEM solution:

```
pde = drsqrdx[x, y] Derivative[0, 1][\[Alpha]][x, y] -drsqrdy[x, y] Derivative[1, 0][\[Alpha]][x, y] == 1

alfa = NDSolveValue[{pde, \[Alpha][x, 0] == 0}, \[Alpha],Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1 , 1 }]  ], AccuracyGoal -> 15,PrecisionGoal -> 8]
Plot3D[alfa[x, y], Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1 , 1 }]  ],AxesLabel -> {x, y, \[Alpha]}]
```

[image]

"approximation error":

```
res = (pde /. Equal -> Subtract) /. \[Alpha] -> alfa;
Plot3D[res, Element[{x, y}, mesh], PlotRange -> All,AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "res"} ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you again @Ulrich. I have checked this method and it seems to be very helpful.
The error you show is still pretty large. By using the options `"MeshOrder" -> 2` and `"MaxCellMeasure" -> .00001` it got better, but it has points where it is still large (up to about 0.5). Is there a way to make the error small, lets say up to $10^-3$? Taking smaller `MaxCellMeasure` doesn't seem to solve it, and takes a very long time to compute.

Comment: @Roy FEM minimizesbweighted residuals of the pde. That's why substituting the solution into pde gives no error measure I think

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are tring to say here, excuse me. Is there a way to minimize it "better", such that the error would be actually small?

Comment: My point is: FEM solution fullfills the pde only for the limiting case of vanishing elementsize. But provides a good solution for small elements

Comment: Thank you very much @Ulrich. While it didn't solve the problem, you helped to understand what happens better!

Comment: @Roy I'm quite sure that this solution solves your problem numerically!

Comment: But the solution in this method still has a large error sadly. I understand that FEM is exact only in the limit of infinite number of element, but maybe there is a better way to discretize or finding the derivatives, or some method for controlling the error with less numerical effort than fining the grid even more (because I tried the maximum my computer can do and the error is still large).

Comment: @Roy FEM gives an accurate solution ( as specified in NDSolve) but the residual of the pde is no measure for the accuracy!

Comment: excuse me, but I probably do not understand that. Why isn't the residual a measure for accuracy? How can a solution to a PDE can be accurate if the residual is large? Is there another quantity you suggest me to check in order the determine how accurate is a solution?

Comment: @Roy In [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178926/large-residual-error-when-solving-a-2d-bvp-with-ndsolve-and-finite-element-metho) is an example of a pde problem which is solved with FEM and shows an accurate approximation compared to the known exact solution. If you plot the residuals `Plot3D[pde - f /. u -> ufun, Element[{x, y}, r]]` you'll see  large residuals!

Comment: thank you, you are so kind! Now I understand what you mean by that FEM gives an accurate solution, I just did know that the residual is not a measure of accuracy of the solution. So you are right, your answer indeed answers my question!
I guess that what I have to figure out now is if there is a way to recover the derivatives from the interpolating function (or from something else) accurately, because I'm actually interested in them.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem seems to be: You have a smooth approximation `A[c]`, but your pde needs  smooth  derivative `A'[c]`! Perhaps you know this derivativefunction???

Because I don't have further knowledge about `A'[c]` I'll use an approximation `A[c]~4 (1 - Sqrt[1 - c])`

```
Plot[{A[c] , 4 (1 - Sqrt[1 - c]) }, {c, 0, 1},PlotStyle ->{Automatic, {Dashed, Red}}]
```

[image]

which fits quite well. Using

```
As = Apply[Function, {c, D[(4 (1 - Sqrt[1 - c]) ), c]}]
```

and

```
arg = Function[{x, y}, 1 - 4/(1/(x + 1)^2 + 1/(y + 1)^2 + 1/(x - 1)^2 + 1/(y - 1)^2)]    (* function argument inside rsqr[x,y] ...*)
```

we get the solution

```
pde = 1/(2 Pi)As[arg[x, y]] Derivative[1, 0 ][arg][x,y] Derivative[0, 1 ][\[Alpha]][x, y] - 
1/(2 Pi) As[arg[x, y]] Derivative[0, 1  ][arg][x,y] Derivative[1, 0  ][\[Alpha]][x, y] == 1 
alfa = NDSolveValue[{pde, \[Alpha][x, 0] == 0}, \[Alpha],Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[]] ] 
Plot3D[alfa[x, y], Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[]]]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Dear @Ulrich, thank you for your answer!

1. Unfortunately I do not know much about the derivative of `A(c)`. How did you know that `4(1-Sqrt[1-c])` would be such a good approximation?
While this approximation is interesting, it is not good enough for what I'm trying to do, so I'll have to stick with `A(c)` itself.

2. I don't think the problem is the smoothness of the derivatives. The solution you show here also have the same problem I showed in the original post: by plotting you can verify that it does not satisfy the PDE. The solution I got using the full `A(c)` looks almost the same.

Comment: @Roy #1: You might improve the approximation by fitting ` A[c]~(4 (1 - Sqrt[1 - c]) +  c1 c   Sqrt[1 - c]^3`. #2: Numerical differentiation is usually a problem. Be aware that the solution you got is a FEM-solution , which only gives good approximation at grid-points of the mesh used by NDSolve

Comment: Thank you @Ulrich. It is a FEM-solution, but isn't the interpolating function gives a good approximation also between the grid points? Taking a denser grid doesn't seem to give a solution that satisfies the PDE near the origin.
I'm aware that numerical differentiation is problematic, but is there a way to find a solution that satisfies the PDE if I use the approximation for `A(c)`? The solution you got also does not satisfy it.

Comment: @Roy At the origin solution seems to jump for `x=0,y=0.0001` .  I' ll append a solution idea based on your approach using `FEM& ElementMeshInterpolation`